Add Native Admob Ads in Kivymd App Using Full Ad Layout
I am trying to add native Admob ads in Kivymd app using jnius, but when open the app, the app closes itself. How can I add native Admob ads so that the ad is between each piece or button? . And for those who help me, it is appreciated and respected
Here is the following code.
from jnius import autoclass,cast 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.utils import platrm
class NativeAdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Add a placeholder for native ad
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="Your App Content"))

        if platform == "android":
            self.load_native_ad()

        return self.layout

    def load_native_ad(self):
    # Import necessary Java classes
        PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
        activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
        LinearLayout = autoclass("android.widget.LinearLayout")
        TextView = autoclass("android.widget.TextView")
        ImageView = autoclass("android.widget.ImageView")
        Button = autoclass("android.widget.Button")
        AdLoader = autoclass("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdLoader")
        AdRequest = autoclass("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest")
        NativeAdView = autoclass("com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView")
        NativeAd = autoclass("com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd")
        ViewGroupLayoutParams = autoclass("android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams")

    # Create a LinearLayout for the native ad
        ad_layout = LinearLayout(activity)
        ad_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
        ad_layout.setLayoutParams(ViewGroupLayoutParams(
        ViewGroupLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroupLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ))

    # AdLoader to load native ads
        def on_native_ad_loaded(native_ad):
        # Create views for the ad
            headline_view = TextView(activity)
            headline_view.setText(native_ad.getHeadline())
            headline_view.setTextSize(20)
            ad_layout.addView(headline_view)

            if native_ad.getImages() and native_ad.getImages().size() > 0:
                image_view = ImageView(activity)
                image_view.setImageDrawable(native_ad.getImages().get(0).getDrawable())
                ad_layout.addView(image_view)

                call_to_action_view = Button(activity)
                call_to_action_view.setText(native_ad.getCallToAction())
            ad_layout.addView(call_to_action_view)

        # Link NativeAd object with NativeAdView
            native_ad_view = NativeAdView(activity)
            native_ad_view.addView(ad_layout)
            native_ad_view.setNativeAd(native_ad)

        # Add the ad layout to the activity's content view
            activity.runOnUiThread(lambda: activity.addContentView(
                native_ad_view, ViewGroupLayoutParams(
                    ViewGroupLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroupLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
            ))

    # Create the ad loader
        ad_loader = AdLoader.Builder(activity, "<your-native-ad-unit-id>") \
            .forNativeAd(on_native_ad_loaded) \
            .build()

    # Request an ad
        ad_request = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        ad_loader.loadAd(ad_request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NativeAdApp().run()

Note that I want a code that works on Android so that the ad appears in the middle of the piece or above the button. I hope that the developers will support me in this area.
